# Frontmost window of the current application that passes a predicate check

Tags: swift, osx

After resigning active state (going to the background), the `mainWindow` property of the main window in the app returns false.

Nevertheless, I need a to find that window even when my app is not active, so I came up with the following code, which works:

```
public let App = NSApplication.sharedApplication() // just some sugar

public extension NSApplication {

    public func frontmostWindow(_ accept: (NSWindow -> Bool)? = nil) -> NSWindow? {
        for windowNumber in NSWindow.windowNumbersWithOptions(0) as? [Int] ?? [] {
            if let window = windowWithWindowNumber(windowNumber) {
                if let accept = accept {
                    if accept(window) {
                        return window
                    }
                } else {
                    return window
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

With this, I can now get the first window of my app in the current ordering that passes the provided predicate check (`accept: NSWindow -> Bool`). This is because I normally would not be interested in the menu bar or the status item, which all have associated windows that belong to my app (which is what I would get if I do not pass any predicate). As an example, say I have some:

```
class PimpedUpWindow: NSWindow, ExtraTranslucent {}
```

the frontmost instance of which I wish to find after the app launches and is no longer the active app. Using the extension above I can:

```
App.frontmostWindow { $0 is PimpedUpWindow }
```

or

```
App.frontmostWindow { $0 is ExtraTranslucent }
```

Of course, I can provide any other predicate of type `NSWindow -> Bool`, but I figure I will often enough want to just check the type or protocol conformance. So I might as well add two convenience methods for just those occasions:

```
public extension NSApplication {

    public func frontmost <T> (windowOfType: T.Type) -> T? {
        return frontmostWindow { $0 is T } as? T
    }

    public func frontmostWindow <P> (conformingTo: P.Type) -> NSWindow? {
        return frontmostWindow { $0 is P }
    }
}
```

Now, I can simply:

```
App.frontmost(PimpedUpWindow)
```

Which actually returns a `PimpedUpWindow?`, and:

```
App.frontmostWindow(ExtraTranslucent)
```

which returns an `NSWindow?`.

All ideas, criticisms, and comments very welcome!

Answer (score 3):

There is a way of improving the code as desired in that it is possible to constrain the type `T` to `T: NSWindow`. Upon introducing this change, however, the function will indeed return the first `NSWindow` in the current ordering, whether or not it is of subtype `T` (too check this you must construct a test that can actually fail, i.e. by having an `NSWindow` of a another type above the window you are looking for - e.g. by adding a status item to your app). There is a workaround, however, as described in [Optional binding succeeds if it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838032/optional-binding-succeeds-if-it-shouldnt). Apart from the solution I stumbled upon in the question (of not constraining `T`), there is a much preferable option discovered by **@vacawama** in the answer to the linked question. The workaround is to generalise the variable to `Any` before type checking, e.g. as follows:

```
public func frontmost <T: NSWindow> (windowOfType: T.Type) -> T? {
    return frontmostWindow { $0 as Any is T } as? T
}
```

This improves the api considerably.

Answer (score 1):

The code bellow seems to do the same with less code. I found the original solution to be a bit cryptic and language specific. The provided code bellow is also easier to modulate, one could imagine getting the backMostWinOfType with a single char change in the sort algorithm. One could argue that running a sort algorithm is superfluous to this task, but it's unlikely to hamper performance as you never have that many windows anyway. Thoughts and corrections are more than welcome.

```
/**
 * Returns the front most window in NSApp of a spedific class or protocol type
 */
class func frontMostWinOfType<T:NSWindow>(type:T.Type)-> T?{
    var windows:Array<T> = []
    for window : NSWindow in NSApp.windows { if(window as? T != nil) {windows.append(window as! T)}}
    windows.sortInPlace { (a, b) -> Bool in return a.orderedIndex > b.orderedIndex}
    return windows[0]
}
```

Comment: How is this better than what the OP have ? At Code Review, we want the code and OP to be better! You need to justify and explain.

Comment: I rather not claim that its better, I Usually leave praise up to other people. I could argue that its less code? I shall begin my future posts with a better explanation. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks, and asking a question like that make it seems like you don't know if this is working for op. You should really take a look a bit around and read the [help] to know what this site is about. Your answer as currently written is not what we really do here. Try to add why you change it like that ? Which did you take in reading the op code to come out with this one.

Comment: Thanks Marc-Andre. To be honest I might be missing something concerning the order of windows, would love to hear back from The author of the original question about this. That being said I will add my order code in a moment and some contextual content as you requested.